# Deployment of Ingress-controler with Helm failed

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, ingress-controller

I tried to install an Ingress-controler on my Kubernetes Cluster with Helm. The installation failed with the following log on the corresponding Pod:

```
{
  "err": "Get \"https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/ingress-nginx/secrets/ingress-nginx-admission\": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout",
  "level": "fatal",
  "msg": "error getting secret",
  "source": "k8s/k8s.go:232",
  "time": "2022-02-22T10:47:49Z"
}
```

The Pod-console shows the following error:

*OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unk*

So the ingress-Pod stops after a few seconds with the error above.

Here is a description of my nodes:

```
NAMESPACE   NAME              STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KER               NEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
            node/kubemaster   Ready    control-plane,master   121d   v1.22.2   192.168.1.38   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS   5.4               .0-100-generic   docker://20.10.7
            node/kubenode     Ready    <none>                 87d    v1.22.4   192.168.1.39   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04 LTS     5.4               .0-94-generic    docker://20.10.7`
```

and the services:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       kubernetes          ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP                  121d
default       nextcloud-service   ClusterIP   10.98.154.93   <none>        82/TCP                   13d
kube-system   kube-dns            ClusterIP   10.96.0.10     <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   120d
```

How can i debug this? What kind of secret is missing ?

**Update:**
i used this description for the deployment:

https://computingforgeeks.com/deploy-nginx-ingress-controller-on-kubernetes-using-helm-chart/
starting from *Option 2: Install Nginx Ingress Controller Kubernetes using Helm*

So the final command is:

```
kubectl create namespace ingress-nginx
```

and then;

```
helm install -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx  -f values.yaml .
```

with corresponding values in values.yaml

**Update 2:**
when i list all secrets i see only this secret:

```
ingress-nginx-admission-token-gbldb
```

which is of course different to..:

```
ingress-nginx-admission
```

is that maybe the reason? Can i change somewhere the name of secret in deployment.yaml?

Comment: It says what the secret is that it is looking for: ingress-nginx-admission however, I am unsure why. This is the default name of various accounts and permissions that are setup with this helm chart but I have never set it. Do you reference it somewhere in your chart? Do you have a link to what you are installing?

Comment: Thanks! I used this description to deploy the ingress controller: https://computingforgeeks.com/deploy-nginx-ingress-controller-on-kubernetes-using-helm-chart/ .... i will add more details to the main description

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5932 a big thread but looks like various potential solutions including upgrading your version of k8s. Good luck!

Comment: I checked several possible solutions, but nothing worked! When i have a look to all secrets i only can find this one:   ingress-nginx-admission-token-gbldb  maybe this is a naming problem? Does the name needs to be exact the same?